# jQuery to populate cascading dropdown from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

[Site here.](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/guestvibe/index.php)

I'm trying to make one form trigger the population of another from a database. I've got the HTML, PHP and database sorted, but I'm struggling with jQuery.

Can someone put me in the right direction? I've Googled to death but I'm slightly limited by the fact that I don't know exactly what to search for.

EDIT:

Here's what I have following your advice. Unfortunately it's still not working.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                       
$('#city').change(function(){
    var $club = $('#club');
    $club.find('option:not([value="default"])').remove(); //Remove previous items
    $.getJSON('GetClubs.php', {city:$(this).val()}, function(clubs){
        $.each(clubs, function(index, city){
            $club.append('<option value="'+city[0]+'">'+city[1]+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<h1>1. Choose your city</h1>
<select name="city" class="dropdown" id="city">
<option value="default" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--- Select your option ---</option>
<?php getCities(); ?>
</select>

<h1>2. Choose your club</h1>
<select name="club" class="dropdown" id="club">
<option value="default" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--- Select your option ---</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$day = date("l");
$time = date("G");

if ($time >= 21) {
    $day = date('l', strtotime($day .' +1 day'));
    }

$city = $_POST['city'];


if ($day == Monday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Tuesday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Wednesday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Thursday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Friday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Saturday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Sunday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();

    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $items[] = array( $row[0], $row[1] );
            }         
    } 

    mysql_close(); 
    // convert into JSON format and print
    echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

Comment: Your requirement is to fill the second dropdown with relevant data depending upon what is selected in the first dropdown? Is this the requirement?

Comment: Yep, that's right. So it'd show you the clubs that are in the city you chose, ordered by day starting with today.

Comment: Then below answers are more than enough. Take help from the link given below in the first answer. For any help post it here.

Comment: I've gone through the code you provided and added it, but nothing has happened. Given that I only have one city at the moment and it's selected automatically, should it still be "$('#city').change(function(){" ?

Comment: By default, let your php code fill the second drop down with the clubs  of the city which is selected by default in the first dropdown. Still you can write onChange event. This will help you if there comes more entry in your first drop down later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#city').change(function(){
    var $club = $('#club');
    $club.find('option:not([value="default"])').remove(); //Remove previous items
    $.getJSON('GetClubs.php', {city:$(this).val()}, function(clubs){
        $.each(clubs, function(index, city){
            $club.append('<option value="'+city[0]+'">'+city[1]+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

You'll also have to remove the `echo "<option..."`.

You should also have a look at [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Let ur first dropdown call a jquery function at "onChange" event. In this function 1) get value of selected option, 2) create an ajax with the example from above link like below code and pass the value to ur GetClubs.php.

```
    $.getJSON('url/GetClubs.php', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
  });

  $('<select/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#secondDropdown');
});
```

This example, of course, relies on the structure of the JSON file:

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Thats it. Data is populated on change of values in your first select box